# UIButton: how to center an image and a text using imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

If I put only an image in a button and set the imageEdgeInsets more close to the top, the image stays centered and all works as expected:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

If I put only a text in a button and set titleEdgeInsets more close to the bottom, the text stays centered and all works as expected:

```
[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -30, 0.0)];
```

But, if I put the 4 lines together, the text interferes with the image and both lost the center alignment.

All my images has 30 pixels width, and if I put 30 in the left parameter of UIEdgeInsetMake for setTitleEdgeInsets, the text is centered again. The problem is that the image never gets centered because it appears that it is dependent of the button.titleLabel size. I already tried many calculations with button size, image size, titleLabel size and never get both perfectly centered.

Someone already had the same problem?

Answer (score 422, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a general solution to positioning the image centered above the text without using any magic numbers. **Note that the following code is outdated and you should probably use one of the updated versions below**:

```
// the space between the image and text
CGFloat spacing = 6.0;

// lower the text and push it left so it appears centered 
//  below the image
CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.frame.size;
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
  0.0, - imageSize.width, - (imageSize.height + spacing), 0.0);

// raise the image and push it right so it appears centered
//  above the text
CGSize titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
  - (titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, - titleSize.width);
```

The following version contains changes to support **iOS 7+** that have been recommended in comments below. I haven't tested this code myself, so I'm not sure how well it works or whether it would break if used under previous versions of iOS.

```
// the space between the image and text
CGFloat spacing = 6.0;

// lower the text and push it left so it appears centered 
//  below the image
CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.image.size;
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
  0.0, - imageSize.width, - (imageSize.height + spacing), 0.0);

// raise the image and push it right so it appears centered
//  above the text
CGSize titleSize = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel.font}];
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
  - (titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, - titleSize.width);

// increase the content height to avoid clipping
CGFloat edgeOffset = fabsf(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0;
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(edgeOffset, 0.0, edgeOffset, 0.0);
```

**Swift 5.0** version

```swift
extension UIButton {
  func alignVertical(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0) {
    guard let imageSize = imageView?.image?.size,
      let text = titleLabel?.text,
      let font = titleLabel?.font
    else { return }

    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
      top: 0.0,
      left: -imageSize.width,
      bottom: -(imageSize.height + spacing),
      right: 0.0
    )

    let titleSize = text.size(withAttributes: [.font: font])
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
      top: -(titleSize.height + spacing),
      left: 0.0,
      bottom: 0.0,
      right: -titleSize.width
    )

    let edgeOffset = abs(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0
    contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
      top: edgeOffset,
      left: 0.0,
      bottom: edgeOffset,
      right: 0.0
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful - thanks! I think a lot of other answers go about this "the hard way" - this looks much better.

Comment: The correct code: `button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, titleSize.height+spacing, -titleSize.width);`

Comment: I found the above to wok, but I have absolutely no mental model for how. Anyone got a link to a pictorial explanation of what things the individual EdgeInsets parameters affect? And why would the text width have changed?

Comment: While setting the imageEdgeInsets, having `-(titleSize.height + spacing)` as `-(titleSize.height - spacing)` worked out for me.

Comment: This doesn't work when the image is being shrunk to fit the button. It appears that UIButton (in iOS 7 at least) uses the image.size, not the imageView.frame.size for it's centering calculations.

Comment: **This would not work with custom font.** From iOS7+, `CGSize titleSize = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel.font}];`

Comment: @Hemang and Dan Jackson, I'm incorporating your suggestions without testing them myself. I find it kind of ridiculous that I originally wrote this for iOS 4, and after this many versions we're still having to essentially reverse-engineer Apple's layout algorithm to get such an obvious feature. Or at least I assume there isn't a better solution yet from the consistent stream of upvotes and the equally hackish answers below (no insult intended).

Comment: this does not work if you set the font to another one and the text size

Comment: Playing with this problem, I've found setting title or image edge insets can modify the frame and sizes of the image view. This means changing the order of setting title and image edge insets changes the outcome if you use `self.imageView.frame.size`. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: test without autolayout from 4s to 6 plus working good, thanx

Comment: In iOS8, I've found it better to use `button.currentTitle` instead of `button.titleLabel.text` especially if the button text will ever change. `currentTitle` is populated right away, whereas `titleLabel.text` can be slow to change which can lead to misaligned insets.

Comment: This does not work if your button has a multiline text. Use boundingRectWithSize to get the height of text then button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(boundingRect.size.height + spacing), 0.0f, 0.0f, -titleSize.width);

Comment: The swift version will cause the content to overflow the size of the button as demonstrated in the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25559946/1552116

there's a solution there as well - I'll edit it into the answer when I get a chance

Comment: I've updated the swift answer to include the solution mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25559946/1552116

The objc C code should be similar but I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to change it confidently

Comment: Okay the reviewers think I shouldn't edit the answer - 

So here's the additional code you need to make the UIButton correct (placed in the end of the swift code)

`let edgeOffset = abs(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(edgeOffset, 0, edgeOffset, 0)`

@JesseCrossen please consider updating your answer to include this bit of code

Comment: @wyu I've incorporated your suggestion. All others please let me know if this broke anything.

Comment: I wrote small extension for positioning image and text inside of button. If you are interested, here is source code. https://github.com/sssbohdan/ButtonAlignmentExtension/blob/master/UIButton.swift

Comment: can anyone explain, how this solution is working ? I'm facing difficulties understanding the values. specially in `self.titleEdgeInsets` the `left: -imageSize.width` portion and in `self.imageEdgeInsets` the `right: -titleSize.width`. How these values work ?

Answer (score 59):

Found how.

First, configure the text of `titleLabel` (because of styles, i.e, bold, italic, etc). Then, use `setTitleEdgeInsets` considering the width of your image:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0]];

// Left inset is the negative of image width.
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -image.size.width, -25.0, 0.0)];
```

After that, use `setTitleEdgeInsets` considering the width of text bounds:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Right inset is the negative of text bounds width.
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-15.0, 0.0, 0.0, -button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width)];
```

Now the image and the text will be centered (in this example, the image appears above the text).

Cheers.

Comment: 7 years, man. Really don't remember. When I asked, I answered myself (my answer was the only one at the time). I've changed the selected answer when the author of the current selected answer focused on eliminate those magic numbers. So, in the selected answer, you can figure out what they mean.

Answer (score 20):

You can do it with this Swift extension, which was based in part on Jesse Crossen's answer:

```
extension UIButton {
  func centerLabelVerticallyWithPadding(spacing:CGFloat) {
    // update positioning of image and title
    let imageSize = self.imageView.frame.size
    self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:0,
                                        left:-imageSize.width,
                                        bottom:-(imageSize.height + spacing),
                                        right:0)
    let titleSize = self.titleLabel.frame.size
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:-(titleSize.height + spacing),
                                        left:0,
                                        bottom: 0,
                                        right:-titleSize.width)

    // reset contentInset, so intrinsicContentSize() is still accurate
    let trueContentSize = CGRectUnion(self.titleLabel.frame, self.imageView.frame).size
    let oldContentSize = self.intrinsicContentSize()
    let heightDelta = trueContentSize.height - oldContentSize.height
    let widthDelta = trueContentSize.width - oldContentSize.width
    self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:heightDelta/2.0,
                                          left:widthDelta/2.0,
                                          bottom:heightDelta/2.0,
                                          right:widthDelta/2.0)
  }
}
```

This defines a function `centerLabelVerticallyWithPadding` that sets the title and image insets appropriately.

It also sets the contentEdgeInsets, which I believe is necessary to ensure that `intrinsicContentSize` still works correctly, which would need to use Auto Layout.

I believe all solutions which subclass UIButton are technically illegitimate, since you are not supposed to subclass UIKit controls. I.e., in theory they might break in future releases.

Comment: Testing on iOS9. The image appears centered, but the text appears to the left :(

Answer (score 13):

Edit: Updated for Swift 3

In case you're looking for a Swift solution of Jesse Crossen's answer, you can add this to a subclass of UIButton:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

    let spacing: CGFloat = 6.0

    // lower the text and push it left so it appears centered
    //  below the image
    var titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    if let image = self.imageView?.image {
        titleEdgeInsets.left = -image.size.width
        titleEdgeInsets.bottom = -(image.size.height + spacing)
    }
    self.titleEdgeInsets = titleEdgeInsets

    // raise the image and push it right so it appears centered
    //  above the text
    var imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    if let text = self.titleLabel?.text, let font = self.titleLabel?.font {
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        let titleSize = text.size(attributes: attributes)
        imageEdgeInsets.top = -(titleSize.height + spacing)
        imageEdgeInsets.right = -titleSize.width
    }
    self.imageEdgeInsets = imageEdgeInsets

    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There are some great examples in here, but I couldn't get this to work in all cases when also dealing with multiple lines of text (text wrapping).  To finally get it to work I combined a couple of the techniques:

1. I used Jesse Crossen example above.  However, I fixed a text height
   issue and I added the ability to specify a horizontal text margin. 
   The margin is useful when allowing text to wrap so it doesn't hit
   the edge of the button:

   ```
   // the space between the image and text
   CGFloat spacing = 10.0;
   float   textMargin = 6;

   // get the size of the elements here for readability
   CGSize  imageSize   = picImage.size;
   CGSize  titleSize   = button.titleLabel.frame.size;
   CGFloat totalHeight = (imageSize.height + titleSize.height + spacing);      // get the height they will take up as a unit

   // lower the text and push it left to center it
   button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 0.0, -imageSize.width +textMargin, - (totalHeight - titleSize.height), +textMargin );   // top, left, bottom, right

   // the text width might have changed (in case it was shortened before due to 
   // lack of space and isn't anymore now), so we get the frame size again
   titleSize = button.titleLabel.bounds.size;

   button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, -titleSize.width );     // top, left, bottom, right
   ```
2. Make sure you setup the text label to wrap

   > ```
   > button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2; 
   > button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
   > button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   > ```
3. This will mostly work now.  However, I had some buttons that wouldn't render their image correctly.  The image was either shifted to far to the right or left (it wasn't centered).  So I used an UIButton layout override technique to force the imageView to be centered.

   > ```
   > @interface CategoryButton : UIButton
   > @end
   >
   > @implementation CategoryButton
   >
   > - (void)layoutSubviews
   > {
   >     // Allow default layout, then center imageView
   >     [super layoutSubviews];
   >
   >     UIImageView *imageView = [self imageView];
   >     CGRect imageFrame = imageView.frame;
   >     imageFrame.origin.x = (int)((self.frame.size.width - imageFrame.size.width)/ 2);
   >     imageView.frame = imageFrame;
   > }
   > @end
   > ```

Comment: Seems like this is a good solution, however shouldn't button.titleLabel.numberOfLines be 0 such that it can be as many lines as it wants?

Comment: In my case, I only wanted up to two lines.  Otherwise, the image would have issues w.r.t. the overall size of the button.

Answer (score 9):

I made a method for @TodCunningham's answer

```
 -(void) AlignTextAndImageOfButton:(UIButton *)button
 {
   CGFloat spacing = 2; // the amount of spacing to appear between image and title
   button.imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
   button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   // get the size of the elements here for readability
   CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.frame.size;
   CGSize titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;

  // lower the text and push it left to center it
  button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, - imageSize.width, - (imageSize.height   + spacing), 0.0);

  // the text width might have changed (in case it was shortened before due to 
  // lack of space and isn't anymore now), so we get the frame size again
   titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;

  // raise the image and push it right to center it
  button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(- (titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, -     titleSize.width);
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

### Updated for Xcode 11+

The insets described in my original answer have been moved to the size inspector in more recent versions of Xcode. I am not 100% clear on when the switch happened but readers should review the size inspector if the inset information is not found in the attributes inspector. Below is a sample of the new inset screen (located at the top of size attributes inspector as of 11.5).

[image: insets_moved_to_size_inspector]

### Original Answer

Nothing wrong with the other answers, however I just wanted to note that the same behavior can be accomplished visually within Xcode using zero lines of code. This solution is useful if you do not need a calculated value or are building with a storyboard/xib (otherwise other solutions apply).

Note - I do understand that the OP's question is one requiring code. I am just providing this answer for completeness and as a logical alternative for those using storyboards/xibs.

To modify spacing on image, title, and content views of a button using edge insets you can select the button/control and open the attributes inspector. Scroll down towards the middle of the inspector and find the section for Edge insets.

[image: edge-insets]

One can also access and modify the specific edge insets for the title, image or content view .

[image: menu-options]

Comment: What I don't understand is why I can't seem to enter negative numbers in storyboard for some values.

Comment: Does it this work for the newer swift version? I can't find the Edge attribute anywhere

Comment: @brockhampton - see updated answer for new location

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer of *[Jesse Crossen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199529/7987502)* for **Swift 4**:

```
extension UIButton {
    func alignVertical(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0) {
        guard let imageSize = self.imageView?.image?.size,
            let text = self.titleLabel?.text,
            let font = self.titleLabel?.font
            else { return }
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: -imageSize.width, bottom: -(imageSize.height + spacing), right: 0.0)
        let labelString = NSString(string: text)
        let titleSize = labelString.size(withAttributes: [kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey: font])
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: -titleSize.width)
        let edgeOffset = abs(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0;
        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: edgeOffset, left: 0.0, bottom: edgeOffset, right: 0.0)
    }
}
```

Use this way:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    button.alignVertical()
}
```

Comment: After many, many hours. This was the only thing that worked :)

Comment: Hi Harry, happy to hear that. Anything related to iOS feel free to ask. Sharing is caring!

Answer (score 6):

Don't fight the system. If your layouts become too complex to manage using Interface Builder + perhaps some simple configuration code, do the layouts manually in a simpler way using `layoutSubviews` - that's what it's for! Everything else will amount to hacks.

Create a UIButton subclass and override its `layoutSubviews` method to align your text & image programmatically. Or use something like https://github.com/nickpaulson/BlockKit/blob/master/Source/UIView-BKAdditions.h so you can implement layoutSubviews using a block.

Answer (score 6):

Subclass UIButton

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat spacing = 6.0;
    CGSize imageSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    CGSize titleSize = [self.titleLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - (imageSize.height + spacing))];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - imageSize.width)/2, (self.frame.size.height - (imageSize.height+spacing+titleSize.height))/2, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - titleSize.width)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.frame)+spacing, titleSize.width, titleSize.height);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With this chunk of code, you will get something like this [image: title and image alignment]

```
extension UIButton {
    func alignTextUnderImage() {
        guard let imageView = imageView else {
                return
        }
        self.contentVerticalAlignment = .Top
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Center
        let imageLeftOffset = (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(imageView.bounds)) / 2//put image in center
        let titleTopOffset = CGRectGetHeight(imageView.bounds) + 5
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, imageLeftOffset, 0, 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(titleTopOffset, -CGRectGetWidth(imageView.bounds), 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote small extension for positioning image and text inside of button. If you are interested, here is source code. https://github.com/sssbohdan/ButtonAlignmentExtension/blob/master/UIButton.swift

Answer (score 4):

UIButton extension with **Swift 3+** syntax:

```
extension UIButton {
    func alignImageAndTitleVertically(padding: CGFloat = 6.0) {
        let imageSize: CGSize = imageView!.image!.size
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -imageSize.width, -(imageSize.height + padding), 0.0)
        let labelString = NSString(string: titleLabel!.text!)
        let titleSize = labelString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: titleLabel!.font])
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height + padding), 0.0, 0.0, -titleSize.width)
        let edgeOffset = abs(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0;
        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(edgeOffset, 0.0, edgeOffset, 0.0)
    }
}
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199529/3659227

Answer (score 3):

Using `button.titleLabel.frame.size.width` works fine only as long the label is short enough not to be truncated. When the label text gets truncated positioning doesn't work though. Taking

```
CGSize titleSize = [[[button titleLabel] text] sizeWithFont:[[button titleLabel] font]];
```

works for me even when the label text is truncated.

Comment: you have botton typo.

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor change to Jesse Crossen's answer that made it work perfectly for me:

instead of:

```
CGSize titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;
```

I have used this:

```
CGSize titleSize = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:button.titleLabel.font}];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of adding a separate answer (for a minor change) you can write this to Jesse directly so he can check and update his [accepted] answer correctly (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

I looked at existing answers but I also found that setting the button frame is an important first step.

Here is a function that I use that takes care of this:

```
const CGFloat kImageTopOffset   = -15;
const CGFloat kTextBottomOffset = -25;

+ (void) centerButtonImageTopAndTextBottom: (UIButton*)         button 
                                     frame: (CGRect)            buttonFrame
                                      text: (NSString*)         textString
                                 textColor: (UIColor*)          textColor
                                      font: (UIFont*)           textFont
                                     image: (UIImage*)          image
                                  forState: (UIControlState)    buttonState
{
    button.frame = buttonFrame;

    [button setTitleColor: (UIColor*)       textColor
                 forState: (UIControlState) buttonState];

    [button setTitle: (NSString*) textString
            forState: (UIControlState) buttonState ];


    [button.titleLabel setFont: (UIFont*) textFont ];

    [button setTitleEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake( 0.0, -image.size.width, kTextBottomOffset,  0.0)]; 

    [button setImage: (UIImage*)       image 
            forState: (UIControlState) buttonState ];

    [button setImageEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake( kImageTopOffset, 0.0, 0.0,- button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just use this category:

```
@interface UIButton (VerticalLayout)  

- (void)centerVerticallyWithPadding:(float)padding;  
- (void)centerVertically;  

@end  


@implementation UIButton (VerticalLayout)  

- (void)centerVerticallyWithPadding:(float)padding 
{      
    CGSize imageSize = self.imageView.frame.size;  
    CGSize titleSize = self.titleLabel.frame.size;  

    CGFloat totalHeight = (imageSize.height + titleSize.height + padding);  

    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(- (totalHeight - imageSize.height),
                                            0.0f,
                                            0.0f,
                                            - titleSize.width);

    self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f,
                                            - imageSize.width,
                                            - (totalHeight - titleSize.height),
                                            0.0f);

}


- (void)centerVertically
{  
    const CGFloat kDefaultPadding = 6.0f;

    [self centerVerticallyWithPadding:kDefaultPadding];  
}  


@end
```

Comment: **This would not work with custom font.** From iOS7+, `CGSize titleSize = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel.font}];`

Answer (score 1):

My use case made insets unmanageable:

1. background image on button stays consistent
2. dynamic text and image changes where the string length and image size varies

This is what I ended up doing and I'm pretty happy with it:

- Create the button on the storyboard with a background image (round circle with blur and color).
- Declare a UIImageView in my class:

  ```
  @implementation BlahViewController {
      UIImageView *_imageView;
  }
  ```
- Create image view instance on init:

  ```
  -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
      self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
      if (self) {
          _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithCoder:aDecoder];
       }
       return self;
   }
  ```
- In viewDidLoad add a new layer to the button for our image view and set text alignment:

  ```
  [self.btn addSubview:_imageView];
  [self.btn.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
  ```
- In the button click method add my chosen overlay image to the image view, size it to fit the image and center it in the button but move it up 15 so I can put the text offset below it:

  ```
  [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blahImageBlah]];
  [_imageView sizeToFit];
  _imageView.center = CGPointMake(ceilf(self.btn.bounds.size.width / 2.0f),
           ceilf((self.btn.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) - 15));
  [self.btn setTitle:@"Some new text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  ```

Note: ceilf() is important to ensure it's on a pixel boundary for image quality.

Comment: Definitely a better approach for my use case too since I'm adding the button to a stack view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want both text and image to be centered horizontally, image above text:
Center the text from interface builder and add a top inset (making room for the image). (leave the left inset to 0). Use interface builder to choose image - it's actual position will be set from code, so don't worry that things will not look ok in IB. Unlike other answers above, this actually works on all currently supported ios versions (5,6 and 7).

In code, just discard the ImageView of the button (by setting the button's image to null) after grabbing the image (this will also automatically center the text, wrapped if necessary). Then instantiate your own ImageView with the same frame size and image and position it in the middle.

This way you can still choose the image from interface builder (though it will not be aligned in IB as in simulator, but then again, other solutions are not compatible across all supported ios versions)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to get this done because I couldn't get image size and text width on my view's constructor. Two minor changes on [Jesse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199529/715451) worked for me:

```
CGFloat spacing = 3;
self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, - image.size.width, - (image.size.height + spacing), 0.0);
CGSize titleSize = [name sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.titleLabel.font}];
self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(- (titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, - titleSize.width);
```

The change are:

- Using `[NSString sizeWithAttributes]` to get text width;
- Get image size directly on the `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me, for several buttons, with different image width and different title length :

Subclass `UIButton`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if let image = imageView?.image {

        let margin = 30 - image.size.width / 2
        let titleRect = titleRectForContentRect(bounds)
        let titleOffset = (bounds.width - titleRect.width - image.size.width - margin) / 2


        contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
            imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, margin, 0, 0)
            titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (bounds.width - titleRect.width -  image.size.width - margin) / 2, 0, 0)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for the button size 80x80 pixels.

```
[self.leftButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0)];    
[self.leftButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, -75.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did make some adjustment to make the image aligned at center horizontal:

```
// the space between the image and text
        let spacing = CGFloat(36.0);

        // lower the text and push it left so it appears centered
        //  below the image
        let imageSize = tutorialButton.imageView!.frame.size;
        tutorialButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
            0, -CGFloat(imageSize.width), -CGFloat(imageSize.height + spacing), 0.0);

        // raise the image and push it right so it appears centered
        //  above the text
        let titleSize = tutorialButton.titleLabel!.frame.size;
        tutorialButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
            -CGFloat(titleSize.height + spacing), CGFloat((tutorialButton.frame.width - imageSize.width) / 2), 0.0, -CGFloat(titleSize.width));
```

Answer (score 0):

is it mandatory to use edge insets? If not, you can try to position respect to center parent view

```
extension UIButton 
{
    func centerImageAndTextVerticaAlignment(spacing: CGFloat) 
    {
        var titlePoint : CGPoint = convertPoint(center, fromView:superview)
        var imageViewPoint : CGPoint = convertPoint(center, fromView:superview)
        titlePoint.y += ((titleLabel?.size.height)! + spacing)/2
        imageViewPoint.y -= ((imageView?.size.height)! + spacing)/2
        titleLabel?.center = titlePoint
        imageView?.center = imageViewPoint

    }
}
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for the use of imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets so it's probable that it's mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the image to the right by the width of the text. Then move the text to the left by the width of the image.

```
UIEdgeInsets imageEdgeInsets = self.remoteCommandsButtonLights.imageEdgeInsets;
imageEdgeInsets.left = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[button.titleLabel font]}].width;
imageEdgeInsets.bottom = 14.0;
button.imageEdgeInsets = imageEdgeInsets;

UIEdgeInsets titleEdgeInsets = self.remoteCommandsButtonLights.titleEdgeInsets;
titleEdgeInsets.left = -button.currentImage.size.width;
titleEdgeInsets.top = 20.0;
button.titleEdgeInsets = titleEdgeInsets;
```

Then adjust the top and bottom insets to adjust the Y-axis. This could likely be done programmatically as well, but should be constant for your image size. Whereas the X-axis insets will need to change based on the size of the text label in each button.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in extension Swift 4.2

```
 func moveImageLeftTextCenter(imagePadding: CGFloat = 30.0){
    guard let imageViewWidth = self.imageView?.frame.width else{return}
    guard let titleLabelWidth = self.titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize.width else{return}
    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: imagePadding - imageViewWidth / 2, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: (bounds.width - titleLabelWidth) / 2 - imageViewWidth, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}
func moveImageRIghtTextCenter(imagePadding: CGFloat = 30.0){
    guard let imageViewWidth = self.imageView?.frame.width else{return}
    guard let titleLabelWidth = self.titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize.width else{return}
    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left:0.0 , bottom: 0.0, right: imagePadding - imageViewWidth / 2)
    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left:0.0 , bottom: 0.0, right:(bounds.width - titleLabelWidth) / 2 - imageViewWidth)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw my 2 cents in, this worked for me:

```
extension UIButton {
  public func centerImageAndTextVertically(spacing: CGFloat) {
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let contentFrame = contentRect(forBounds: bounds)
    let imageFrame = imageRect(forContentRect: contentFrame)
    let imageLeftInset = bounds.size.width * 0.5 - imageFrame.size.width * 0.5
    let imageTopInset = -(imageFrame.size.height + spacing * 0.5)
    let titleFrame = titleRect(forContentRect: contentFrame)
    let titleLeftInset = ((bounds.size.width - titleFrame.size.width) * 0.5) - imageFrame.size.width
    let titleTopInmset = titleFrame.size.height + spacing * 0.5
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: imageTopInset, left: imageLeftInset, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: titleTopInmset, left: titleLeftInset, bottom: 0, right: 0)
  }
}
```