# Position image in UIButton for all states

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIButton: how to center an image and a text using imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451223/uibutton-how-to-center-an-image-and-a-text-using-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgei)

I'm customizing the placement of the image and label of my UIButton but it's only set on the initial state.  What the hack, how do I ensure the positioning for all 4 button states?

This is the code I'm using.  The poisoning works for the first state but gets reset on the other states.

```
CGRect imgRect = reviewsButton.imageView.frame;
imgRect.origin.x = 10;
imgRect.origin.y += 4;    
reviewsButton.imageView.frame = imgRect;

CGRect lblrect = reviewsButton.titleLabel.frame;
lblrect.origin.x = 85;
reviewsButton.titleLabel.frame = lblrect;
[reviewsButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.192 green:0.198 blue:0.206 alpha:0.15]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get the desired layout to work with UIButton so I created a custom UIView and handled touches there.

Answer (score 5):

There are `UIButton` properties which have been made specially for this

```
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentEdgeInsets
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets imageEdgeInsets
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets titleEdgeInsets
```

Use this property to resize and reposition the effective drawing rectangle for the button image. You can specify a different value for each of the four insets (top, left, bottom, right). A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving it closer to the center of the button. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge. Use the UIEdgeInsetsMake function to construct a value for this property. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

Answer (score 0):

@jspooner Settings the button frame after you are finished altering the imageview frame and label frame might do the trick.

Comment: thanks but that didn't effect the other button states

Answer (score 0):

You should create your image and then apply it to the button states:

```
UIImage* reviewButtonImage = [UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:/*path*/];
[reviewButton setImage:reviewButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateDisabled|UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Thx but the only problem is `UIImage` doesn't have a view or allow you to set the origin.  I do like how you placed many states into the forState method.  I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Your remark of UIImageView and frame is right. I made a mistake. I deleted my mistake from the answer

Comment: @gsempe the multiple states doesn't work