# Several images on one UIButton

Tags: iphone, image, dynamic, uibutton

I need some help and advice on using multiple images simultaneously on the same custom UIButton.

Here is what I have:

1. An array holds the core definitions for a number of buttons.
2. Depending on a set of parameters, several buttons are being dynamically generated and displayed.
3. Depending on actions and answers some are removed from view, some change their appearance and meaning (i.e. new buttons replace them)

...Ultimately, the number of buttons that could be created is vast...

*Under the hood:*
There are a few template PNG files that I use to create the faces of the buttons. [This article](http://blog.chomperstomp.com/creating-dynamically-re-sizable-buttons-for-iphone-apps/) was of great help. These are the faces for normal and active state. The handling of dynamic creation and removal from view was done with the wonderful help I got from postings here!

**QUESTION:**
*Is there a way that I can use a third image (PNG with transparency) to have an icon or a symbol instead if the button textual title/label?*

As you might have guessed, i would like to avoid having a huge number of unique hard-coded faces for each of the numerous buttons and would like to only add a small graphical symbol to the face of the dynamically generated and stretched button. *IS THIS POSSIBLE?*

Thank you!

P.S. [Found the answer **here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451223/uibutton-how-to-center-an-image-and-a-text-using-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgei)

Comment: Try subclassing `UIButton` and add another `UIImageView` as a subview of your custom button. Then write another method that sets the image of the new `UIImageView`. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
UIImageView *buttonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"png_image_with_transparency.png"]];
[buttonImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)];

[button addSubview:buttonImageView];
```

Hope that helps.