# Highlighted Multiple UIImageView on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Based on this: [Several images on one UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307880/several-images-on-one-uibutton)

I can add images on UIButton, but I can't show the highlighted state UIImageView inside the UIButton.

Have set the highlighted image as follows:

```
imageOneOnButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option-unchecked"];
imageOneOnButton.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option-checked"];

imageTwoOnButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option-unchecked"];
imageTwoOnButton.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option-checked"];
```

Unfortunately on its action:

```
sender.highlighted = YES // or NO doesn't work
sender.imageView.highlighted = YES // or NO doesn't work as well
```

Is there any way that I can simulate this,

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option-unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option-unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

button.highlighted = YES // or NO <-- works!
```

using my approach?

Comment: So you have two image views inside one button? You may need to subclass your button and override its `setHighlighted:` setter to call `setHighlighted:` on each of its imageviews. The reason `sender.imageView.highlighted = YES` isn't working is because (I assume) that neither imageview is associated with the button's built-in `.imageView` property.

Comment: @user2320861 I guess you're right. Thanks, will try it.

Comment: Ok, if it works let me know and I'll post it as an answer that you can accept.

Comment: @user2320861 it works. you might want to post it as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two image views inside one button? You may need to subclass your button and override its setHighlighted: setter to call setHighlighted: on each of its imageviews.

The reason sender.imageView.highlighted = YES isn't working is because (I assume) that neither imageview is associated with the button's built-in .imageView property