# How to vertically centre align * (star) in label or button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, vertical-alignment

[image: alignment problem of *]

I tried centre aligning symbol star(*) in a custom button but I couldn't.

How to vertically centre align just like other characters(1,2...) ?

Comment: can try use this unicode:http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2217/index.htm

Comment: If you want that to be centred , you should do some customisation on that. For '*' it won't happen by default.

Comment: Characters are not made to be centered. They are made to be aligned to the baseline. If you want a character to be aligned differently, you have to do the alignment manually or use an image.

Comment: @zp_x - how to do this ... i tried assigning U+2217 to title..But didn't work out

Comment: @RajuBhaiRocker just go to page, and copy paste it to your code. Copy  ∗ to your code. or you can use "\u{2217}"

Comment: Wouldn't you be easier using an image of '*'?

Comment: I intend to do this without image

Answer (score 34):

Just use a different character. Rather than * (ASTERISK U+002A) there are many other options that are similar and centered:

U+2217  ASTERISK OPERATOR   ∗ (this is centered in some fonts, but not others)

U+273B  TEARDROP-SPOKED ASTERISK    ✻

U+FE61  SMALL ASTERISK  ﹡

U+FF0A  FULLWIDTH ASTERISK  ＊

U+2735  EIGHT POINTED PINWHEEL STAR ✵

U+2736  SIX POINTED BLACK STAR  ✶

[FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) gives my favorite search interface. But you can also just pull up the character viewer (^⌘Space).

Comment: For a centered dot: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm

Comment: For a centered dot in Ubuntu ⋅

Comment: low asterisk:  `⁎`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this line of code.

```
button.titleEdgeInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(left,bottom,right,top)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good solution for you by 'algal', just play with the value to adjust it as you prefer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294816/4205432

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        button.centerLabelVerticallyWithPadding(5)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension UIButton {

    func centerLabelVerticallyWithPadding(spacing:CGFloat) {
        // update positioning of image and title
        let imageSize = self.imageView!.frame.size
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:0,
            left:-imageSize.width,
            bottom:-(imageSize.height + spacing),
            right:0)
        let titleSize = self.titleLabel!.frame.size
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:-(titleSize.height + spacing),
            left:0,
            bottom: 0,
            right:-titleSize.width)

        // reset contentInset, so intrinsicContentSize() is still accurate
        let trueContentSize = CGRectUnion(self.titleLabel!.frame, self.imageView!.frame).size
        let oldContentSize = self.intrinsicContentSize()
        let heightDelta = trueContentSize.height - oldContentSize.height
        let widthDelta = trueContentSize.width - oldContentSize.width
        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:heightDelta/2.0,
            left:widthDelta/2.0,
            bottom:heightDelta/2.0,
            right:widthDelta/2.0)
    }
}
```

[image]