# iOS: How to set 0.5 space in a string when showing a UILabel?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton, uilabel

I need 0.5 space, showing a `UILabel`.

Like to set a button's title as the following image:

[image]

**Here is what I achieved:**

[image: 5]

There is a small difference between the two button's layout.
**Here is my code:**

```
UIButton * tmpBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 84, 26)];
[tmpBtn setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"btnBgImage"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[tmpBtn setTitle: @"1   跳过" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
// there is 3 space
tmpBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
tmpBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 0);
[self.view addSubview: tmpBtn];
```

There is 3 space in the text. I need 2.5 space.

Is there anyway to achieve it?

Comment: see this once may be it helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451223/uibutton-how-to-center-an-image-and-a-text-using-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgei

Comment: May you can using the attributed to support your case

Comment: What I need is to control the distance between the left part and the right part of the string. @Anbu.karthik

Comment: `NSKernAttributeName` helps @Quoc Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

With `NSKernAttributeName`, Can control more precisely.

```
UIButton * tmpBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 84, 26)];
[tmpBtn setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"btnBgImage"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
tmpBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
tmpBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 0);
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"1   跳过"];
// 3 spaces
[str setAttributes: @{NSKernAttributeName: @(-1)} range: NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
[tmpBtn setAttributedTitle: str forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview: tmpBtn];
```